# How to get field value in template Django

Tags: python, django

I want to show some specific fields in my template from the value of another field. I'm rendering fields manually.

models.py

```
OPTIONS = (
    ('YES', 'Yes'),
    ('NO', 'No'),
)

question = models.CharField(
    max_length=3,
    choices=OPTIONS,
    verbose_name="Are you employed now?")

company_name = models.CharField(
    max_length=30,
    blank=True)
```

info.html

```
<strong>{{ form.question.label_tag }}</strong>
{{ form.question }}

{% if form.question.value == "YES" %} <!-- I want to do something like this and then rendering others fields -->
    <strong>{{ form.company_name.label_tag }}</strong>
    {{ form.company_name }}
{% endif %}
```

The if statement above doesn't work for me, is there a way to get that? Thanks a lot.

Comment: when you render your form in a template, the `{{ form.field_name.value }}` is `None`, unless you had assigned it an `initial` value

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ varname }}
```

Read the documentation for the template that you are using,